# Is this still TRUE randomization?

Tags: java

this is the case:

my programm requires X random elements of an Y-length array.
X is always lower than Y

so what i do:
WAY#1:

```
1. shuffle the array
2. get the X elements from index 0 to X-1
3. (back to step 1) repeat like 2.000.000 times or more.
```

since shuffling the array takes lot of resources i want to make my programme faster.
i thought of something like this:

WAY#2:

```
1. find out how often X fits into Y (asume X = 6, and X = 20)
2. shuffle the array
3a. get the X elements from index 0 to 5
3b. get the X elements from index 6 to 11
3c. get the X elements from index 12 to 17
(index 18 and 19 will not be used in this case)
4. (back to step 2) repeat like 2.000.000 times or more.
```

After some trials i get with both ways the expected result to 3rd decimal. which would be absolutely fine for my purpose.

WAY#2 is 25-30% faster than WAY#1

What do you think? 
Should i accept a tiny adulteration for higher performance or is it just bad habit and should be avoided?

Comment: What are these randomly selected numbers for?

Comment: Because, if they are all intended for the same target - then NO. It's not OK. Otherwise, it might do.

Comment: Have you considered using java.util.Random to pull from one array and put into another?

Comment: Yes, he's right. You could just remove/get (whatever you need) from the set at random locations of the array X times.

Comment: these numbers alter a final result object/array. so they are all intended for the same target.

Comment: well, duplicate picks from the array are not allowed. have to be X different locations of the array. maybe i get you wrong?